# Recreate Tables in another Database from Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, postgresql-9.5

I made an application using django 3.1 and I want to run the code on a different computer, I have created a database in that computer and I want to create the tables. I am using postgres and I am aware that we can create the tables manually using sql commands but I have a lot of tables. I was wondering if I can make them using commands from django since I have them in my models.py file.

I have tried doing `py manage.py makemigrations` and `py manage.py migrate` but the tables were not created instead it showed comments like -
No changes deteted and  No migrations to apply.

Here is my settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for Analyticweb project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os 
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '______'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'website.apps.WebsiteConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'crispy_forms',
    'rest_framework',
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    # 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Analyticweb.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Analyticweb.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '______',
        'HOST': '________',
        'PORT': '________',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'website/static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assetsmain')


# Upload Media Files
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')

# Rest-Framework Parser

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
    'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
    ),
     'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
     'PAGE_SIZE': 10, 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add your app to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: try this: python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb

Comment: @YousufM.N it says `Unknown command: 'syncdb' Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
`

Comment: @inquisitive are your database settings correct? Please add them to the question (hide sensitive details like password etc.).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

Django can require you to specify the apps in `makemigrations`. So just run something like `python manage.py makemigrations app1 app2 app3` where `app1, app2, app3` are apps in your project's root.

Comment: It happens when you have deleted the migrations folder (or its `__init__.py` file). Also one needs to make sure their app is in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: @nonamorando I have tried that, the tables are not being created in the database.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat I have not deleted and the app is in the `INSTALLED_APPS`